# Change LOT and LOF from \section to \subsection

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I want the tables of contents to look like the first image. I used:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
    \subsection{\listtablename{}}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \subsection{\listfigurename{}}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
         {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

To make it look like I want, but that does that no tables show up in the TOT. Do anyone know of a way to do it?

[image]

[image]

```
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % Gjør det mulig å bruke norske bokstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % fontenc 
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % Grafisk pakke
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}               % For å sette marginer
\usepackage{float}                              % Plassering av tab/fig
\usepackage{url}                                % Håntering av URL:er
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}                   % Removes indent (works the same as \noindent )
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}                           % Brukes til a forandre mellomrom rundt overskrifter
\usepackage{natbib}                             % Bibliography
\usepackage{gensymb}                            % Adds symbols, as degree sign, etc.
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}      % Setter inn innholdsfortengelse i innholdsfortengelse + nr. på referanser
\usepackage{afterpage}                          % For nye komandoer
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}               % For tabeller
\usepackage{tikz}                               % For organisazons kart
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}                           % Gant diagram
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}                       % Brukes i oversettning
\usepackage{translator}                         % Brukes til å oversette tekst fra \userpackage til annet
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime}                 % Viser dato \today i ISO format
\usepackage{pdflscape}                          % For landscape modus for enkelt sider, spesefik for compiler
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}                           % Ha etter alle andre pakker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `\@starttoc{lot}` (tables) and `\@starttoc{lof}` (figures). Also you want `\subsection*`.

```
\documentclass{book} % or whatever class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoftables{%
  \subsection*{\listtablename}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
          {\MakeUppercase\listtablename}%
  \@starttoc{lot}%
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
  \subsection*{\listfigurename}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
          {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{Abc}

\begin{figure}
X
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
Y
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\section{Def}

\begin{figure}
X
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
Y
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]